# Possible orders of normal subgroups using only the elements in $G$ and their orders

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I am told some information about a group $G$ of order $168$. All we are told about G is that: It has one element of order one, $21$ elements of order $2$, $56$ elements of order $3$, $42$ elements of order $4$ and $48$ elements of order $7$. and later it will be proved to be simple. But for now I am asked:

By looking at the possible orders of subgroups $N$ of $G$, show that if $N$ is a non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $G$, then $|N| ∈ \{2, 4\}$ by using the following fact: For $N$, a normal subgroup of index $n$ of $G$, let $a$ be an element of order $m$. Then if gcd$(m,n)=1$ then $a\in N$.

So at the moment we are not using the fact that $G$ is simple, this will be proved later on.

So I have tried using the fact that $168=|N||G:N|$. I also know that $|G:N|=|G/N|=n$ but don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Have you come across Sylow's theorems yet?

Comment: Yes I have, I wondered about using them for this but couldn't quite see how

Comment: Well, then you could first consider the case in which $m$ is prime. What can you tell about the Sylow-$m$ subgroups? What does that imply for the element $a$? And how do you proceed in the case where $m$ is composite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of order $84$. By the fact given, $N$ must contain every element of order $3$ and $7$. But $104 > 84$.

Similarly, if $|N| = 56$ and $N$ is normal (of index $3$), $N$ must contain every element of order $2,4$ and $7$. They don't fit.

Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear now, I can do the rest fine. Just one more thing.. using the fact that $|N|\in\{2,4\}$, how could I then show $G$ is simple. I know this would mean showing that $|N|$ isn't actually either $2$ or $4$, since a simple group has no non trivial proper normal subgroups. I've tried doing it with Sylow theorems but got stuck, is there a better route to go down?

Comment: You should ask that as another question, I think.